# Breakpoint not hit in .NET Core ASP.NET MVC WebApi when using Visual Studio Core when targeting .NET 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, project.json

I'm writing a .NET Core MVC Application targeting Framework 461 instead of .NET Core. Reason: I am using a library which is not yet ready for .net core but will be soon.

I am doing this in Visual Studio Code and have several questions:

1. Debugging starts but breakpoints are not hit. Can't see why as the controller call is successful.
2. Why does the build process produces an exe instead of a dll when switching the framework from core to net 461 in project.json
3. Why is there an exe file beneath debug/net461/ & debug/net461/win7-x64.

I assume I'm doing something completely wrong with the build process in launch.json & task.json or with the project.json but I can't see the problem. I think all questions are related to my problem so I raise them in one thread.

**UPDATE 1:**
Opened the project.json in full Visual Studio 2015, hit F5 and debugging works perfekt. So must be an issue with my visual studio code config. Works with IIS Express & Kestrel.

**UPDATE 2:** 
Set emitEntryPoint to false. Now it produces a dll, but can no longer run the the application now. different error...jfy

**project.json**

```
{

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
    },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Management.Automation": "6.1.7601.17515"
    }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "BeyondAgent"
  }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "launch",
                "preLaunchTask": "build",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\net461\\win7-x64\\BeyondAgent.exe",
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "externalConsole": false,
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
            },
            {
                "name": ".NET Core Attach",
                "type": "coreclr",
                "request": "attach",
                "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
            }
        ]
    }
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\project.json"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

**code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BeyondAgent.Services;
using BeyondAgent.ViewModels;

namespace BeyondAgent.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DscController : Controller
    {

        IViewModelService _viewModelService;
        IDscPowerShellService _dscPowerShellService;

        public DscController(IDscPowerShellService dscPowerShellService, IViewModelService viewModelService)
        {
           //BREAKPOINT HERE NOT HIT! _dscPowerShellService = dscPowerShellService;
            _viewModelService = viewModelService;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Well I mean this `"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\bin\\Debug\\net461\\win7-x64\\BeyondAgent.exe"` would suggest that it'll build as an exe

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I don't think so. I think this is what I configured to launch after it build as the output is not build as dll, so I changed to exe. PDB Files in place so I though debugging should work...